# What opens the new locked containers on Streets of Tarkov?

Tags: escape-from-tarkov

Patch 0.13 has allowed us to take our first peek at the new *Streets of Tarkov* location. It contains a few containers that elsewhere are generally open, or easily opened if only one finds the key clearly describing its use.

So far I have spotted:

1. a *Merin* branded red car with a locked trunk, similar to those on Lighthouse location
2. some safes in the pinewood hotel, 2 of which only accessible after unlocking doors
3. some of the well known toolboxes, some of which showing as "locked":

[image: A locked Toolbox]

Is there a way to get these open, and will doing so reveal anything inside?

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

The locked safes at the pinewood hotel can all be opened using the [USEC second safe key](https://escapefromtarkov.fandom.com/wiki/USEC_second_safe_key), short name "USEC 2".
I have only checked them a few times, so far opening them has never revealed anything inside
(I did crouch to check the lower compartment aswell).